# ListView Checkbox Save State

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, checkbox

I am using Checkbox with each and every list item, and when user do tap on any of the checkbox i am storing that list item into SQLite database, but whenever i do restart my app not getting check for list items those i checked earlier.

So How do I save state to Checkbox ?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);          
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

        boolean strDataExist = activity.myDb.Exists(actorList.get(position).getName());
        if(strDataExist)
        {
            actorList.get(position).setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            actorList.get(position).setChecked(false);
        }

        v.setTag(holder);

    } 
    else 
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();           
    }
```

Comment: where are you setting the checked value for that checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In getView method, the code should be

```
    if(strDataExist)
    {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Comment: thanks i have just replaced actorList.get(position).setChecked(true); with holder.checkBox.setChecked(true); and i am done..

Comment: You are welcome. can simplify the code with this `holder.checkBox.setChecked(strDataExist);` only instead write if else statement.

Answer (score 4):

You should check every data before inflating whether that data is in DB or not, on the base of result you should check the value of checkbox, you are not checking.

You need to check

```
holder.checkBox.setChecked(true/false);
```

Comment: i have updated my code, check above but still facing same issue, where i am missing

Comment: You need to check =>  holder.checkBox.setChecked(true/false);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question, but I'm going to try help you.

I think that you want to inicializate your `checkbox` with `checked` or not depending if you have saved into `database` previously.

In the method `getView` you should check if the service exists in the database with method `public boolean Exists(String strServiceName)`  (you shoud use lowercase for method's name).

...

```
holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
holder.checkBox.setChecked(exists(actorList.get(position).getName().toString()));
```

Regards.

UPDATE
If you want to save the service status if the the service name exists in the database. That coul be a solution :

```
getView(...){
 //...
 if (databaseHandler.exists(serviceName)){
  Service service = new Service(serviceName, holder.checkBox.isChecked());
  databaseHandler.save(service);
 }
}
```

Comment: yeah exactly i would like to save state of checkbox if list item name exists into database, but i am not getting how do i check that name exists or not into database in getView(..) method

Answer (score 0):

try this way,this worked for me

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final Context context;
    private List<ModelPooja> listData;

    public CustomAdapter(Context mainActivity, List<ModelPooja> listData) {
        context = mainActivity;
        this.listData = listData;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_poojaselection, null);
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojaname);
            holder.checks = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_poojacheck);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checks.setFocusable(false);

        if (listData.get(position).isselected) {
            holder.checks.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.checks.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.checks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean b) {

                if (checkMaxLimit()) {

                    if (listData.get(position).isselected && b) {
                        holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                        listData.get(position).isselected = false;

                    } else {
                        holder.checks.setChecked(false);
                        listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Max limit reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (b) {
                        listData.get(position).isselected = true;
                    } else {
                        listData.get(position).isselected = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.tv.setText(listData.get(position).getPOOJA_LISTING_NAME());
        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean checkMaxLimit() {
        int countermax = 0;
        for(ModelPooja item : listData){
            if(item.isselected){
                countermax++;
            }
        }
        return countermax >= 5;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
        public CheckBox checks;
    }
}
```